# Windows 10 Change network to work or home

Tags: windows, networking

I cannot find anything on this.

I have a VPN, and for me to access my VPN and LAN I need to set this to home network, but I can't find this option.

Anyone know?

Comment: In Windows 10 you can choose between "Private" and "Public" network types. What you want is Private.  Here's how:  http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6815-network-location-set-private-public-windows-10-a.html.  BTW, if your UAC setting is at it's highest level, you won't be able to change between Private/Public.  UAC needs to be one notch down from max (the default out-of-box setting).

Comment: Woops forgot there's a third network type called "Domain", but that's not likely applicable to you.